# How to compare string from cell with string from inputBox()

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spread sheet that look like so:

```
Group   | Name   | Title
-----------------------------------
X         WS       -
X         DH       -
X         M        -
X         DH       -
X         WS       -
```

I want to loop through all the cells in name and replace the initial there with their full name in addition to adding the correct title. My script is **failing to accurately compare the strings and go into the if-statement**:

```
Sub enterNameAndTitle()

    lastCell = InputBox("Last cell")
    rInitials = InputBox("Initials")
    rFullName = InputBox("Full Name")
    rTitle = InputBox("Title")

    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In Range("b2:b" & lastCell).Cells

        MsgBox (cell.Text & " : " & rInitials)

        If StrComp(UCase(cell.Value), UCase(rInitials)) = 0 Then
            cell.Value = rFullName
            ActiveSheet.Cells(cell.Row, cell.Column + 1).Value = rTitle
        End If

    Next cell

End Sub
```

So I first collect the data and then loop through all the values. Does anyone know what I am doing incorrectly? Why doesn't it compare the string accurately?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong, but there are 2 things I would try

One is to use TRIM to make sure neither string has leading or trailing blanks

The 2nd is to change the if to  `if(ucase(trim(cell.value))=ucase(trim(rInitials)))`

Comment: I tried this but it keeps returning "false", I am not sure why this isn't working

Comment: Solved it! I had to use CStr() on both of the strings to force their types. I think it is because cell.Value returns a Variant object.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was one of differing types and the only way that seemed to work for me was to re-cast both variables as type String using CStr()

```
Sub enterNameAndTitle()

    Dim lastCell As String
    lastCell = InputBox("Last cell")

    'Cast to string
    Dim rInitials As String

    rInitials = CStr(InputBox("Initials"))
    Dim rFullName As String
    rFullName = InputBox("Full Name")
    Dim rTitle As String
    rTitle = InputBox("Title")

    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In Range("b2:b" & lastCell).Cells

        Dim cellText As String

        'Cast to string
        cellText = CStr(cell.Text)

        If (Trim(UCase(cell.Value)) = Trim(UCase(rInitials))) Then
            MsgBox ("test1")
            cell.Value = rFullName
            ActiveSheet.Cells(cell.Row, cell.Column + 1).Value = rTitle
        End If

    Next cell

End Sub
```